# How do I add texture regions to buttons

Tags: libgdx, textures

I'm trying to add some texture regions to some buttons that I plan on putting in a scroll pane. I'm pretty sure I've gotten the scroll pane part down but I'm not so sure about the regions part. Any tutorial that I've found regarding scroll panes uses normal text to fill in the tables. Here's what I have so far I'm lost on how to add the different texture regions to the buttons.

```
    TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas("data/StoreAtlas.pack");
    uiskin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("SkinLocation.jpg"), atlas);
    uiskin.addRegions(atlas);

    TextureRegion Magnet = uiskin.getRegion("Magnet");
    TextureRegion Life = uiskin.getRegion("Life");
    TextureRegion BonusCoins = uiskin.getRegion("BonusCoins");
    TextureRegion Ice = uiskin.getRegion("Ice");
    TextureRegion LavaBombs = uiskin.getRegion("LavaBombs");
    TextureRegion Foreground = uiskin.getRegion("Foreground");
    TextureRegion Background = uiskin.getRegion("BackGround");

    Button MagnetButton = new Button();
    Button LifeButton = new Button();
    Button BounusCoinsButton = new Button();
    Button IceButton = new Button();
    Button LavaBombsButton = new Button();
```

I'm new at this so if someone knew of a good explanation or example that would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `TextureRegionDrawable` for the desired image and place it in the constructor of the button. So, in your case, you would do something like...

```
Button MagnetButton = new Button(new TextureRegionDrawable(Magnet);
Button LifeButton = new Button(new TextureRegionDrawable(Life));
//etc...
```

What this essentially does is it changes the attribute `up` for the button's style to the specified `Drawable`. There are other attributes such as `down` and `over` that would show the specified image when the button is pressed down or moused over. If you don't specify those attributes, it defaults to whatever you set `up` to, which should be enough for your case.

However, if you ever want to do anything more complex, you may want to consider using a Skin. In your case, the skin you created is invalid, as you're using a .jpg file, while Skin files are .json files. You can read more about Skins [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin).